# Audio player app with sound waveform

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any audio player for iPhone that has a sound waveform display and most importantly lets you slide/swipe on that waveform display to left and right to go back and forth a few seconds on the audio file?

I am looking for the iOS version of this android app: [Auto Repeat Player - listening](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yhkwon44.autorepeat)

Comment: have you seen Soundcloud?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii yes but does sound cloud let me upload files from the phone storage?

Comment: https://soundcloud.com/upload SO yes, If that answers your question, please answer it and close the question by ticking on the greyed icon that will appear after the answer.